# Paypal website payment hosted pro "Please select a valid card type." in iFrame

Tags: magento, paypal

I am trying to update an existing Magento 1.9 EC site to start to use PayPal Website Payment Pro as payment method but am hitting an issue with the behaviour within the iframe.

I have created a sandbox account for both the buyer and business, the settings are working and I can make the payment if I use the "Pay with Paypal" button. The sandbox credit card also works if in the PayPal page I use it without being logged in.

But if I try to use the credit card in the iFrame I have the "Please select a valid card type." message show up. Invalid credit cards will not show that specific message.

It looks like it wants me to make an action to select Visa as the type, but the card type cannot be selected, it detects the number as a Visa card, greys out the other types and keeps the Visa one visible.
This seems to be all happening within the iFrame I use to host the result of the initial request which builds the form on the paypal site.

Also, the rest of the integration seems to be working, if we use the "Pay with Paypal" button, complete the credit card payment on that page we go back to the proper return page and the order records the payment in Magento.

Which makes me wonder why there is only an issue within that iFrame?
Is that solution not working? Should we look at some of the other options?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your developer paypal account.

choose the merchant account you have created and click the profile tab

[image]

Use the credit which is displayed under Funding Tab..

You can add more cards by logging into your sandbox.paypal.com using merchant account u created and goto profile->credit cards which is under financial information

Hope this helps